# how to display all values which don't match in in clause?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

For Ex:

```
MY_TABLE
COL1->'P1','P2','P3'
```

OUTPUT SHOULD DISPLAY `P4,P5`

I tried:

```
select col1 from my_table where col1 not in ('p4','p5');
```

Comment: select col1 from my_table where col1 not in ('p1','p2','p3'); table should have values for p4 and p5.

Comment: actually i have a range values from p1 to p5 .I want to display those values which are not in column.

Comment: if its a numeric value you can use between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should have that range of values in a proper SQL table.  Lacking this, you could use an on-the-fly CTE to hold the range:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'p1' AS col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'p2' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'p3' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'p4' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'p5' FROM dual
)
SELECT t1.col1
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN my_table t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Thsnk you so much.